# Swift update tableview async with S3 download function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, uiimage

I have an async problem - I have a function that loads images from S3, stores them into an array of UIImages (here called Images)

I also have a tableview that loads its cells from firebase fetched data, my question is, how to update the cell image once the async finishes loading ?

I'm also afraid that the queue of images won't match exactly the indexPath.row since some images might load faster than other images.

```
 func download(key:String, myindex:NSIndexPath, myrow:Int) -> NSString {
    let path:NSString = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingString("image.jpg")
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path as String)

    //    let downloadingFilePath = downloadingFileURL.path!
    let downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
    downloadRequest.bucket = "witnesstest/" + rootref.authData.uid
    downloadRequest.key = key
    downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = url

    switch (downloadRequest.state) {
    case .NotStarted, .Paused:
        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
        transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWithBlock({ (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if let error = task.error {
                if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain as String
                    && AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType.Paused {
                        print("Download paused.")
                } else {
                    print("download failed: [\(error)]")
                }
            } else if let exception = task.exception {
                print("download failed: [\(exception)]")
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    let tempimage:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path as String)!
                    print("dl ok")
                    self.Images.append(tempimage)

            })
            }
            return nil
        })

        break
    default:
        break
    }
    return path
}
```

and the cell :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: MainWitnessTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RIcell") as! MainWitnessTableViewCell

        // populate the cell
        let postitem = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.postOwner.text = postitem.author
        cell.postContent.text = postitem.content
        cell.postDate.text = postitem.createon

        let myindex = indexPath
        let myrow = indexPath.row




       // cell.cellImage.image = Images[indexPath.row] // returns array index out of range

     //   download(postitem.imagekey, myindex: myindex, myrow: myrow)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why don't you have an image property on postItem? That way the image is associated with a post rather than separately in an array libel to get out of order.

Comment: hello, because when I tried that, the postitem.image would be nil until it finally loads, and I didn t find a way to counter the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the imageView's image after you download the image and at the same time set postitem's image property (assuming you add one). It's hard for me to understand everything your download method is doing, but I think the gist of what you want is something like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: MainWitnessTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RIcell") as! MainWitnessTableViewCell

        // populate the cell
        let postitem = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.postOwner.text = postitem.author
        cell.postContent.text = postitem.content
        cell.postDate.text = postitem.createon

        //postitem should also have a imageURL property or you should have some way of getting the image url.
        if post item.image == nil{
            dispatch_queue_t imageFetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("image fetcher", NULL)
            dispatch_async(imageFetchQ, ^{

               let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: postitem.imageURL)
               let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
               postitem.image = image
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   //the UITableViewCell may have been dequeued and reused so check if the cell for the indexPath != nil
                   if tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) != nil{
                       cell.imageView.image = image
                   }
    })

})





    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a cache of images and the indices they're supposed to be associated with, and then instead of loading all the images in your function, you would create the table view, and then for that specific cell ask for the image from your server or from the cache if it's already there, rather then trying to download them all async at one time